# Mysql-Codeigniter Get Products Related to a Product

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I am making an SQL query where I want to get related products to a product based on category.
My Query is as follows:

```
$sql=
        "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE products.id IN (
        SELECT product_categories.product_id FROM `product_categories` WHERE product_categories.category_id=(
        SELECT product_categories.category_id FROM `product_categories` WHERE product_categories.product_id=".
        $this->db->escape($product_id)."));";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result(static::$model_name);//return related products array
```

But this also gives me the original product I don't want the original product, I couldn't do it using JOINS so I switched to basic queries still stuck. how can I exclude it in this query?

Comment: add `products.id != " . $this->db->escape($product_id) . "` to your query

Comment: @ravisachaniya thanks alot solved by ANDing this with the last result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve that with a join:

```
$sql = 'SELECT products.*
        FROM products
        JOIN product_categories ON  product_categories.product_id = products.id
        WHERE product_categories.product_id != '. $this->db->escape($product_id);
return $this->db->query($sql)->result(static::$model_name);//return related products array
```